# Java 8 Stream function grouping to Map where value is a Map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I am trying to collect result of a list and organise them into a Map where the value is a Map:

```
private Map<Organisation, Map<LocalDate, Status>> getSummaries(final List<Status> summaries) {
    return summaries
            .stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Status::getOrganisation,
                    toMap(Status::getProcessedDate, Function.identity())));
}
```

I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key` error as `getProcessedDate()` is same for different values in the list.

Is there a way I can merge multiple objects with same `processeddate` into the map?

e.g say I have these objects in the the list:

```
Summary(ProcesseDate=2020-01-30, Organisation=ABC, status=OK, statusCount=5)
Summary(ProcesseDate=2020-01-30, Organisation=ABC, status=FAILED, statusCount=2)
Summary(ProcesseDate=2020-01-30, Organisation=APPLE, status=OK, statusCount=5)
Summary(ProcesseDate=2020-01-30, Organisation=APPLE, status=REJECTED, statusCount=5)
```

Values contained in the map should be:

```
key=ABC
   value { key=2020-01-30, value= Summary(ProcesseDate=2020-01-30, Organisation=ABC, status=OK, statusCount=5), Summary(ProcesseDate=2020-01-30, Organisation=ABC, status=FAILED, statusCount=2) }
```

When I tried `toMap(Status::getProcessedDate, Function.identity(), (v1, v2) -> v2)));` it removes one of the entries

Comment: Change the type of value of the map to a list, and combine them in this phase (v1, v2) -> v1.add(v2); return v1;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might just be looking for a nested grouping if you don't want to merge data and don't have unique keys:

```
private Map<Organisation, Map<LocalDate, List<Status>>> getSummaries(final List<Status> summaries) {
    return summaries
            .stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Status::getOrganisation, groupingBy(Status::getProcessedDate)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge keys, you can use `Map.merge()`.

`map.merge(key, value, bifunction);` checks to see if `key` is present in the map. If it is not, it calls `map.put(key, value);` If it is, it applies `bifunction` to the existing key and value, and stores that in the map.

For example, if you have a `Map<String, Integer>` that counts occurrences of a word in a passage, you could use the following:

```
List<String> words = ...
Map<String, Integer> wordCount = ...

words.forEach(s -> wordCount.merge(s, 1, (word, count) -> count + 1));
```

You can use this to avoid adding duplicate keys in your code.